# Cartesian <--> Cylindrical conversion in Paraview

Tags: paraview

With VisIt, I use `OppAtts -> Transforms -> Transform -> Coordinate` to change the data from Cartesian to cylindrical coordinates (or vice versa). Is there an Option like this in Paraview?

Comment: There is the Transform Filter, under the "Filters" main menu item. However, it seems that this [only works on certain types of data](http://paraview.uservoice.com/forums/11350-general/suggestions/1206709-transform-filter-should-work-on-all-types-of-data).

Answer (score 0):

There's no automatic way to do this.

You should apply the Transform filter and do the transformations by hand.

[Help link!](http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/docs/reference/CRC-formulas/node42.html)